# Querying data with nested relationships

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a `user` table that has a relationship to my `accounts` table. My accounts table has a relationship to the `account_permission` table which is used to define permissions for accounts.

A `user` may have multiple `accounts` and he may have permissions to view his own accounts or other user's accounts.

I'm not sure how to query all the accounts that a user has and the accounts that he has permissions to view.
I thought that `Account.query.filter_by(owner_id = user).all()` would include `permissions` in it's results since it has a db relationship with a backref to the `account_permission` table but that is not the case.

```py
# querying information
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    user = User.query.filter_by(email = current_user).first()
    accounts = Account.query.filter_by(owner_id = user).all() # how do I get all the accounts that the user has permissions to?
```

```py
# user model
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    isAdmin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    accounts = db.relationship('Account', backref='owner')
```

```py
# accounts model
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from app import db, ma

class Account(db.Model):
    account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    permissions = db.relationship('AccountPermission', backref='permissions')

    def __init__(self, account_id, description, owner_id):
        self.account_id = account_id
        self.description = description
        self.owner_id = owner_id

class AccountSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('account_id', 'description', 'owner_id')
        ordered = True

class AccountPermission(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    account = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('account.account_id'))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

class AccountPermissionSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('account', 'user_id')
        ordered = True
```